# How to Make a Point Orbit a Line, 3D

Tags: math, vector, 3d, line, plane

Essentially, i want to find the equation of the ring that circles a point in space, this ring is perpendicular to a normal away from this point.

I have a line, in the form of 2 points, **L1**, **L2**;

I have the normal from L1->L2, **N**;

I have the plane that is normal to L1->L2, which L1 lies on. **ax + by + cz = d**;

I have the radius away from L1, **R**;

-> I want to make a point **V**, orbit this line around point L1;

I think I have to make a circular equation in this plane with L1 as the origin. I have no idea how to plot a 2d equation onto a 3d plane.

Or maybe someone knows how to do do this another way, cross products or something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: If it is not prgramming related then delete this and post it at [Math.SE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem actually requires a nontrivial solution. Suppose you have U = normalize(L2 - L1) and two unit vectors V and W such that U, V, W are pairwise orthogonal.

Then f(a) = L1 + R * (V * cos(a) + W * sin(a)) for angles a is the equation for the circle you want.

How can you find W given U and V? W can just be their cross product.

How can you find V given U? This is where it's not straightforward. There are a whole circle of such V that could be chosen, so we can't just solve for "the" solution.

Here's a procedure for finding such a V. Let U = (Ux, Uy, Yz).

If Ux != 0 or Uy != 0, then V = normalize(cross(U, (0,0,1)))
Else if Ux != 0 or Uz != 0, then V = normalize(cross(U, (0,1,0)))
Else U = 0, error

Note: You can negate W if you want your point to cycle in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank You!  f(a) = L1 + (R * ((U * cos(a)) + (V * sin(a))))

Where N, U, V are all perpendicular to each other. Thanks for the Alg. to find the 3 perpendicular vectors

Comment: I notice you don't use W in the calculation of 'f', so I assume that 'a' is an angle from the new 'W' axis (towards 'V').  Is that correct?  If so, shouldn't the first term be W*cos(a)?  I am asking since I don't really understand where this equation comes from.

Comment: @melston There was a typo in the definition of f(a). I had U * cos(a) + V * sin(a). It should be V * cos(a) + W * sin(a). Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: @melston The equation comes from the standard parametric equation for a circle, f(a) = (cos(a), sin(a)), which can also be written as f(a) = (1,0) * cos(a) + (0,1) * sin(a). I hope it's clear now how this generalizes to 3 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  Actually, it is the whole cross product thing that still mystifies me.  In fact, my problem has to do with an Android/OpenGL ES app I am writing and it looks like the W term needs to be negated but, other than that, it all seems to work correctly (ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714014/3d-point-on-circumference-of-a-circle-with-a-center-radius-and-normal-vector).  Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I think I almost understand what is going on.  Instead of using `W = U cross V` I reversed it to `W = V cross U` and I didn't need to negate the W term.  I still don't have a good intuitive feel for it but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Rodrigues' Rotation Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) (try to find better description)